# Añadiendo cooldown en base a datetime y guardandolo en un archivo.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x

Llevo ya algunas horas intentando crear un código que si el mensaje del usuario fue enviado hace 5 segundos o menos, no pueda escribir (cooldown) o no reciba respuesta por cantidad de segundos, el usuario al escribir y recibir una respuesta por parte del programa.

La hora del envío del mensaje se guarde en un archivo llamado `cooldown.txt` para que el cooldown quede guardado incluso al reiniciar el programa y al volver a abrir el programa, siga en cooldown si el tiempo aún no ha pasado. Lo ideal es que fuera con un `return` para no recibir respuesta, este es un código pequeño que hice en base a un código más grande que es el que uso. El problema se encuentra al intentar verificar los segundos.

Aquí el codigo:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import datetime as DT
mensaje=None

cooldownfile = open("cooldown.txt","r+")
horacooldown= cooldownfile.read()
cooldownfile.close()
while mensaje!= 'salir':
    mensaje=input("Ingrese su mensaje → ")
    if horacooldown and DT.datetime.now() < horacooldown + DT.timedelta(seconds=5): #450
        print("Cada 5 segundos puede enviar mensajes")
        time.sleep(5)
        cooldownfile = open("cooldown.txt","r+")
        cooldownfile.write(DT.datetime.now())
    if mensaje=='hola':
        print ("Hola usuario")
        cooldownfile = open("cooldown.txt","r+")
        cooldownfile.write(str(DT.datetime.now()))

    elif mensaje =='info':
        print("Este es un codigo de ejemplo")

print("Saliendo del codigo.")
```

El error que obtengo

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
can only concatenate str (not "datetime.timedelta") to str
  File "DIRECCION/temp888.py", line 11, in <module>
    if horacooldown and DT.datetime.now() < horacooldown + DT.timedelta(seconds=5): #450
```

Esto es lo que queda registrado en el documento de texto y no la hora:

```
<built-in method now of type object at 0x70EFC3B0>
```

Lo ideal es que guardara así la hora, en otro código me funcionó perfecto y quedaba así : `2020-07-25 21:24:34.747884`

He intentado pasar la hora a un `datetime.now` en string pero no he podido y no lo he añadido al código. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varios problemas con el código.

**Leer hora desde archivo**

```
cooldownfile = open("cooldown.txt","r+")
horacooldown= cooldownfile.read()
cooldownfile.close()
```

Estas abriendo un archivo que puede no existir. Eso produce una excepción (FileNotFoundError).

Estás leyendo directamente el archivo en la horacooldown. Eso deja un string en la variable, no una fecha-hora.

*Soluciòn*

Crear un función que lea la hora desde el archivo. Si el archivo no existe, retorna None.

La fecha, leida como string, debe ser convertida a datetime using `strptime` antes de poder compararla. Eso evita el error que señalas en tu pregunta.

```
def leerhora():
    hora = None
    try:
        cooldownfile = open("cooldown.txt","r+")
        hora = cooldownfile.read()
        hora = DT.datetime.strptime(hora, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
        cooldownfile.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass

    return hora
```

**Grabar lo mismo de distinta manera**

Grabas la fecha-hora en dos partes, y lo haces de manera distinta:

```
cooldownfile = open("cooldown.txt","r+")
cooldownfile.write(DT.datetime.now())
```

y aqui:

```
cooldownfile = open("cooldown.txt","r+")
cooldownfile.write(str(DT.datetime.now()))
```

En una grabas el objeto datetime, en el otro grabas la representaciòn en caracteres del mismo objeto.

Otro error: abres el archivo con opción "r+". Eso falla si el archivo no existe. Si vas a grabar, no a leer, usas "w".

*Solución*

Usar funciones para delegar el código repetitivo y asegurarse de que siempre funcione igual:

```
def grabarhora(hora):
    cooldownfile = open("cooldown.txt","w")
    cooldownfile.write(str(hora))
    cooldownfile.close()
```

**Otros errores**

La `horacooldown` nunca es actualizada dentro del `while`. Tienes que actualizarla tras cada mensaje.

Estas usando `time.sleep()`, pero no importaste `time`.

En lugar de escribir directamente el valor de la espera (5 segundos), declara una variable. Asi podras probar tu programa con distintos intervalos sin introducir errores (producto de no cambiar el valor en todas partes).

**Resumen**

Aplicando todo lo anterior, la versión correcta del programa es:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import datetime as DT
import time

def leerhora():
    hora = None
    try:
        cooldownfile = open("cooldown.txt","r+")
        hora = cooldownfile.read()
        hora = DT.datetime.strptime(hora, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
        cooldownfile.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass

    return hora

def grabarhora(hora):
    cooldownfile = open("cooldown.txt","w")
    cooldownfile.write(str(hora))
    cooldownfile.close()

mensaje=None
intervalo = 5
horacooldown  = leerhora()

while mensaje!= 'salir':

    if horacooldown and DT.datetime.now() < horacooldown + DT.timedelta(seconds=intervalo): #450
        print("Cada %d segundos puede enviar mensajes" % intervalo)
        time.sleep(intervalo)

    mensaje=input("Ingrese su mensaje → ")
    horacooldown = DT.datetime.now()

    if mensaje=='hola':
        print ("Hola usuario")
    elif mensaje =='info':
        print("Este es un codigo de ejemplo")

    grabarhora(horacooldown)

print("Saliendo del codigo.")
```

Comment: *Si vas a grabar, no a leer, usas "w".* Aclarar que "w" limpia el archivo e inicia desde cero, se debe de usar "a" para guardar el registro.

Comment: @gcoronel99. Tu recomendación es errónea. Con "a", el archivo crece indefinidamente cada vez que se graba la fecha/hora actualizada, pues nada se borra. Más aún, ahora tienes un archivo con un montón de fecha/hora que no sirven para nada, y al usuario sólo le interesa el último valor. Recomendación: prueba primero, opina después.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación y la corrección, era justo lo que necesitaba!